# How to i append the output from beautifulsoup to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am relatively new to `python`. I am planning to

a) obtain a list of URLs from the following url (https://aviation-safety.net/database/) with data from the year 1919 onwards (https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1919).

b) obtain the data (date, type, registration, opreator, fat., location, cat) from 1919 to current year

However, i ran into some problems and am still stuck in a)

Any form of help is appreciated, thank you so much!

```
#import packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#start of code
mainurl = "https://aviation-safety.net/database/"
def getAndParseURL(mainurl):
   result = requests.get(mainurl)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
   datatable = soup.find('a', href = True)


#try clause to go through the content and grab the URLs
try:
   for row in datatable:
      cols = row.find_all("|")
      if len(cols) > 1:
         links.append(x, cols = cols)
         except: pass


#place links into numpy array
links_array = np.asarray(links)
len(links_array)


#check if links are in dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(links_array)

df.columns = ['url']
df.head(10)
```

i can't seem to be able to get the URLs

would be great if i could get the following

S/N      URL
1         https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1919
2         https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1920
3         https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1921

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not extracting the `href` attributes from the tags you are pulling. What you want to do is find all `<a>` tags with links (which you did, but you need to use `find_all` as `find` will just return the first 1 it finds.) Then iterate through those tags. I choose to just have it look for the substring `'Year'` and if it does, put that into the list.

```
#import packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#start of code
mainurl = "https://aviation-safety.net/database/"
def getAndParseURL(mainurl):
   result = requests.get(mainurl)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
   datatable = soup.find_all('a', href = True)
   return datatable

datatable = getAndParseURL(mainurl)

#go through the content and grab the URLs
links = []
for link in datatable:
    if 'Year' in link['href']:
        url = link['href']
        links.append(mainurl + url)


#check if links are in dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(links, columns=['url'])

df.head(10)
```

**Output:**

```
df.head(10)
Out[24]: 
                                                 url
0  https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.ph...
1  https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.ph...
2  https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.ph...
3  https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.ph...
4  https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.ph...
5  https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.ph...
6  https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.ph...
7  https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.ph...
8  https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.ph...
9  https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.ph...
```